# Google pay parsing json token

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I am getting a 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll exception when attempting to parse a google pay token,(sample token from https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography#using-tink)

```
{
    "protocolVersion":"ECv1",
    "signature":"TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ",
    "signedMessage":" {\"encryptedMessage\":\"ZW5jcnlwdGVkTWVzc2FnZQ==\",
    \"ephemeralPublicKey\":\"ZXBoZW1lcmFsUHVibGljS2V5\",
    \"tag\":\"c2lnbmF0dXJl\"}"
} 
using JSONObject.Parse()

after removing special characters i end up with the following 

 {"protocolVersion":"ECv1",
 "signature":"TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ",
 "signedMessage":" 
 {"encryptedMessage":"ZW5jcnlwdGVkTWVzc2FnZQ==",
 "ephemeralPublicKey":"ZXBoZW1lcmFsUHVibGljS2V5","tag":"c2lnbmF0dXJl"}"}

 The exception is as followed: Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

 in terms of the class being used, I cannot provide the full code as it is work related, but the following is the code where JSON is used

        googlePayXml = Regex.Replace(googlePayXml, "[^A-Za-z0-9+/=\s]", "")
        googlePayXml = Regex.Replace(googlePayXml, "\\", "")

        'Base64 decode Google Pay PaymentData'
        Dim decodedGooglePayPaymentData As String = 
        Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(googlePayXml))
        Dim paymentData As JObject = 
        JObject.Parse(decodedGooglePayPaymentData)
```

can someone tell me what could be wrong with the formatting?

Comment: What is the message of exception? Can you share the code of deserializing json and the class to which you are deserialize to?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Well the formatting as above is broken, if that is what you are trying to decode. Note that signedMessage has a quote after the colon. It should not. Also, are you sure that there is no message with that exception other than the type of exception?

Answer (score 0):

like see sharper mentioned, the formatting was incorrect of the sample token, once i moved bracket outside, json.parse worked